# SQL запрос на выборку данных из таблиц

Tags: sql, запрос, count

Таблица Students имеет поля StudentId, FirstName, LastName, Group и содержит информацию о студентах института. Таблица Exams имеет поля StudentId, ExamName, Result и содержит результаты экзаменов студентов.

a) написать SQL запрос, который выводит имена и фамилии студентов у которых больше двух экзаменов с результатом меньше 3.

b) написать SQL запрос, который выводит название групп, в которых таких студентов больше 10

пункт а) написан:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Students.StudentsId) as count, FirstName, LastName
FROM Students 
INNER JOIN Exams ON Students.StudentsId = Exams.StudentsId
WHERE Exams.Result < 3 
GROUP BY Students.StudentsId, FirstName, LastName 
HAVING count(Students.StudentsId) > 2
```

помогите пожалуйста с пунктов b

Comment: про count() почитайте

Comment: почитала, но если я задаю COUNT(Students.StudentsId) для выборки первого запроса, на второй count sql у меня ругается

Comment: Показывайте Ваши попытки решить задачу - пусть и неудачные. Но с объяснением логики, которую Вы пытались реализовать. А любые упоминания о решённом задании удалите - они никому тут не нужны.